# Apache POI and Pandas (with openpyxl) don't work well together

Tags: java, python, pandas, apache-poi, openpyxl

We are generating excel report from Java with Apache POI library and then we send this report to python script. This python script processes the report with pandas and appends excel file (openpyxl library) with some new sheets and tables. However, when I open the final excel report, I lose all the formatting from the table and  get the following error:

```
Removed Part: /xl/styles.xml part with XML error.  (Styles) Catastrophic failure Line 1, column 801.
Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet27.xml part
```

I also noticed that when I open excel file after first (Apache POI) processing and save it, python processing works fine and I don't get any errors. So I suspect there is a issue with Apache POI.

Does anybody know why this happens and how could I resolved it?

Comment: Make sure you're using the most recent versions of Apache POI and Pandas?

Comment: I am using most recent versions of both POI and Pandas

Comment: You will need to unzip the resulting invalid .xlsx file (it's actually a zip-file) and take a look at the XML-files that are reported as invalid to see what happened there while processing with openpyxl. I expect that openpyxl is not expecting the XML to be slightly different out of Apache POI (while still being valid in Excel itself)